# Making Google Oauth work locally with subdomains

Tags: asp.net, oauth, asp.net-identity, google-oauth

I'm developing a website using ASP.NET identity that will work with subdomains that identify a client using some information from [here](http://benjii.me/2015/02/subdomain-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/) I've got subdomains working locally, but I can't get it to work with OAuth.

For example, if I got to `https://localhost:44301` and try to login with Google, everything is fine. In my Google console I have `https://localhost:44301` under "Authorized JavaScript origins" and `https://localhost:44301/signin-google` under "Authorized redirect URIs". But when I go to `https://foo.localhost:44301` Google will respond with:

> Error: invalid_request
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: https://foo.localhost:44301/signin-google

When you try to log in. I can add `https://foo.localhost:44301` to "Authorized JavaScript origins" in the Google console, but it won't let me add `https://foo.localhost:44301/signin-google` under authorized redirect URIs because it will complain:

> Invalid Redirect: https://foo.localhost:44301/signin-google must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org)

Some other [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24838149/1250301) suggest redirecting all subdomains to a single domain for OAuth, but ideally I want to keep logins per subdomain. So if you use google to sign it to `foo.mydomain.com` it will be separate from `bar.mydomain.com` and I don't think that'll work if I have to redirect both to the same single domain (although I'm not sure that's going to work without separate projects in Google.

Answer (score 5):

Google and in general other OAuth2/OIDC providers will support redirecting to sub-domains. Your specific problem is that you seem to be trying to use sub-domains of `localhost` which is in the list of Special-Use Domain Names ([RFC6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761)) and it seems Google has additional constraints for those ones.

However, this is not a real limitation because on production you'll use a public top-level domain from from where you'll have the specific sub-domains.

If you need to have this working for local development, you can use [localtest.me](http://readme.localtest.me/) which allows you to set a sub-domain you like (`foo.localtest.me` and `bar.localtest.me`) while still ensuring that the domain resolves to your local machine (`127.0.0.1`). This should stop Google from complaining about it...