# Oauth2 redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, cloud9

I've setup an environment in Cloud9 to create a website in Rails. I'm currently trying to enable login via Gmail, using the google oauth2 gem, but i ran into this problem and no matter where i look, every solution i've found does not seem to work.

Here is the error:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAiWL.png)

And here is my google development urls:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmg8j.png)

(Sorry, seems like i can't upload images directly to the post yet)

Comment: Have you tried to add a link from your redirect_uri to authorized domains?

Comment: Yes, it simply adds the c9users.io link, not the full one

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having this issue because Google's OAuth does not support wildcard subdomain matching and your app is basically a subdomain on Cloud9. Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342471/3251051).

I found a post with similar issues on [Cloud9 forums](https://community.c9.io/t/google-oauth-issue/16718/3)

I googled with "OAuth c9.io".

Comment: I've read these before, but it seems the Google Developer website changed, and now not even registering subdomains is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the authorized redirect URIs?. It´s in the Credentials tab. You must edit your OAuth 2.0 client IDs and set the URIs there.

Steps:

- Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard
- Select the project
- Click on Credentials link on the left menu
- Edit the OAuth 2.0 client IDs clicking the pencil next to it
- Add your Authorized redirect URIs (https://domain/users/auth/google/callback or something similar)