# How can I persist a subdomain through an oauth login process?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0

I know that subdomains shouldn't be used in oauth, as in the request should come to and from the host without the subdomain to prevent a vector of attach, but how can we keep that information through the process and return the user there when it's completed?

For example, the user browses to `https://company.supercoolproduct.com/Account/Login` and goes to use oauth. The provider has and will only have registered `https://supercoolproduct.com/signin` as a redirect URL so if we try `https://company.supercoolproduct.com/signin` then it will fail. What is a method of passing "company" through the process so that the final redirect after acquiring the access_token goes back to where they came from?

Comment: Except that this has nothing to do with google and that information is specific to that implementation.

Comment: Also, the question was "What is a method of passing "company" through the process so that the final redirect after acquiring the access_token goes back to where they came from?"

Comment: Did you read the answers? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24838149/224370 in particular.